# Visible and invisible with a checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, visibility

i have a screen with 5 lines.each line has 3 editTexts.after the 5th line there is a checkbox and below it another line with 3 edittexts.i would like,the 6th line to be invisible when i firstly open my app,and when the users checks the checkbox,the line to appear.is this possible?thanks

```
  final CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.box);
            checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Perform action on clicks, depending on whether it's now checked
                    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                       ?????????????
                    } else {
                       ???????????
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: to answer your question yes it is possible

Comment: is there any idea how to make it work?:)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your layout xml file add

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

to the View that have to be hidden at startup.

Then in your code:

```
myHiddenView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

to make it visible.

Comment: thanks!!thats working!but if i unckeck the button,how can i set it Invisible again??

Comment: MyHiddenView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);